# Can something help me to see how to deal with single quote escaping in the following scenario

Tags: javascript, internationalization

We write js programs for clients which allow them to craft the display text. Here is what we did

We have a raw js file which replaced those strings with tokens, for example

```
month = [_MonthToken_];
name = '_NameToken_';
```

and have a xml file to allow user to specify the text like

```
<xml>
    <token name="MonthToken">'Jan','Feb','March'</token>
    <token name="NameToken">Alice</token>
</xml>
```

and have a generator to replace the token with the text and generate the final js file.

```
month = ['Jan','Feb','March'];
name = 'Alice';
```

However, I found there is a bug in this scenario. When somebody specifies the name to be "D'Angelo" (for example.) the js will run into a error because the name variable will become

```
name='D'Angelo'
```

We have thought of several ways to fix the problem but none of which are perfect.

We may ask our clients to escape the characters, may it seems not appropriate given that they may not know js and there are more cases to escape (", ), which could make them unhappy :|

We also think of changing the generator to escape ', but sometimes the text may be replacing an array, the single quote there should not be escaped. (there are other cases, we may detect it case by case, but it is tedious)

We may have done something wrong for the whole scenario/architecture. but we don't want to change that unless we have confirmed that it is definitely necessary.

So, is there any solution? I will look into every ideas. Thank you in advanced!

(I may also need a better title :P)

Comment: A standard string [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) should be all you need `str.replace(/'/g, '\\\'');` Otherwise without you being more specific then it would be difficult to answer your question as it stands.

Comment: @Xotic750 I can not simply escape the single quota. you can see the example: month is a array with a token MonthToken, so the single quote in this token should not be escaped.

Comment: Why do you need the `'` around each month token, is it really necessary? I don't see how your XML generates/is translated to Javascript. There is no way for us to guess how your generator is working.

Comment: @Xotic750 The month is just a example to show that some array declaration also has token to be replaced. I don't have to make the ' around each month token. But since the program has been released, it would be troublesome to change that, especially the xml file is created by client. You can image the generator to be something extracts the text out of the xml file and then replaces the corresponding token in the raw js file. (it has two input, the xml file and a js file with token, one output, the final js file.) Thank you.

Comment: I guess the questions are then, what is the most troublesome and what can and can not be fixed now that we have released our API? I think this is what is know as "a rock and a hard place", and the other phrase that springs to mind regarding fixing it is "having to bite the bullet".

Comment: simply JSON.stringify the values before plopping them into your XML.

Answer (score 1):

I think your xml schema is poor designed, and this is the root cause of your problems.

Basically, you are forcing the author of the xml to put Javascript code inside of the `name="MonthToken"` element, while you pretend that she can do this without Javascript syntax knowledgement. I guess that you are planning to use `eval` on the parsed element content to build `month` and `name` variables.

The problem you discovered it's not the only one: you also are subject to Javascript code injection: what if a user forge an element such as:

```
<token name="MonthToken">alert('put some evil instruction here')</token>
```

I would suggest to change the xml schema in this way:

```
<xml>
    <token name="MonthToken">Jan</token>
    <token name="MonthToken">Feb</token>
    <token name="MonthToken">March</token>
    <token name="NameToken">Alice</token>
</xml>
```

Then in your generator, you'll have to parse each `MonthToken` element content, and add it to the `month` array. Do the same for the `name` variable.

In this way:

1. You don't use `eval`, and so you have no possibility of code injection
2. Your user doesn't no more have to know how to quote month names
3. You automatically handle quotes or apostrophe in names, because you are not using them as js code.

If you want `month` variable to become a string when user enter just a month, then simply transform the variable: with something similar to this:

```
if (month.length == 1) {
    month = month[0];
}
```